# I have two forms both with an id as the primary key, I want the id entered in the first form to update in the next form

Tags: php

I have two forms both with an id as the primary key,I want the id entered in the first form to be used by the next form.the current forms are not updating the id.The first form is for patient registration and the primary key is the id,the second form is for entering further patient details such as diagnosis and medicine prescribed,the second form should use the id from the first form and refuse to enter any id's other than those saved in the database from the first form.included in the code snippet are two forms the addpatient.php and addprescription.php

```html
<?php
session_start()
?>

<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$occupation=$_POST['occupation'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$db=@mysql_select_db("hms",$con)or die(mysql_error());
$str="insert into patients values('$id','$name','$age','$gender','$occupation','$mobile','$address')";
$res=@mysql_query($str)or die(mysql_error());

if($res>=0)
{
echo'<br><br><b>Patient added !!<br>';
}

?>
<html>

<body style="background-image:url(background4.jpg)">
<br>
<a href="home.html"><b>Click here to return to the home page</b></a>
</body></html>




//end of first form addpatient//

//start of second form addprescription




<?php
session_start()
?>

<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$medicine=$_POST['medicine'];
$diagnosis=$_POST['diagnosis'];
$instructions=$_POST['instructions'];
$doc_name=$_POST['doc_name'];
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$db=@mysql_select_db("hms",$con)or die(mysql_error());
$str="insert into prescription values('$id','$medicine','$diagnosis','$instructions','$doc_name')";
$res=@mysql_query($str)or die(mysql_error());
if($res>=0)
{
echo'<br><br><b>Prescription added !!<br>';
}

?>
<html>
<body style="background-image:url(background4.jpg)">
<br>
<a href="home.html"><b>Click here to return to the home page</b></a>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Please convert your db connection in mysqli or pdo.

Comment: If what I understand is true than you need to save your id in a session variable and then reuse the id in your 2nd form and after that making it empty.
`$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id']`
In the 2nd form get the id
`$id=$_SESSION['id'] `

Answer (score 0):

```html
//this is the html for the addpatient.html//

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Patient Registration Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
        <script>
        function validate()
    { 
       if( document.PatientRegistration.id.value == "" )
       {
         alert( "Please provide valid ID!" );
         document.PatientRegistration.id.focus() ;
         return false;
       }
       if ( document.PatientRegistration.name.value == "" ) 
       {
         alert( "Please provide your  Name!" );
         document.PatientRegistration.name.focus() ;
         return false;
       }

       if( document.PatientRegistration.address.value == "" )
       {
         alert( "Please provide your Postal Address!" );
         document.PatientRegistration.address.focus() ;
         return false;
       }

       if ( ( PatientRegistration.sex[0].checked == false ) && ( PatientRegistration.sex[1].checked == false ) )
       {
       alert ( "Please choose your Gender: Male or Female" );
       return false;
       }   
       if( document.PatientRegistration.occupation.value == "" )
       {
         alert( "Please provide your  Occupation!" );
         document.PatientRegistration.occupation.focus() ;
         return false;
       }


     if( document.PatientRegistration.age.value == "" )
       {
         alert( "Please provide your age!" );
         document.PatientRegistration.age.focus() ;
         return false;
       }
    }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="addpatient.php" method="post" name="PatientRegistration" onsubmit="return(validate());">

        <table cellpadding="2" width="20%" bgcolor="99FFFF" align="center"
        cellspacing="2">

            <tr>
                <td colspan=2>
                <center><font size=4><b>Patient Registration Form</b></font></center>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="id" id="id" size="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"
                size="30" ></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Postal Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address" id="address" size="30"></td>
            </tr>



            <tr>
                <td>Sex</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" size="10">Male
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" size="10">Female
                </td>
            </tr>
    <tr>
                <td>Occupation</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="occupation" id="occupation" size="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="age" id="age" size="30"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Mobile</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="mobile" id="mobile" size="30"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="reset">
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>


//this is the html for the addprescription.html//

<html>
<head>
 <title>Patient Registration Form</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="validate.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="addprescription.php" method="post" name="PatientPrescription" onsubmit="return(validate());">

 <table cellpadding="2" width="20%" bgcolor="99FFFF" align="center"
 cellspacing="2">
 
  <tr>
   <td colspan=2>
   <center><font size=4><b>Patient Prescription Form</b></font></center>
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>ID</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="id" id="id" size="30"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>Medicine</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="medicine" id="medicine"
   size="30"></td>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
   <td>Diagnosis</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="diagnosis" id="diagnosis" size="30"></td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
   <td>Instructions</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="instructions" id="instructions" size="30"></td>
  </tr>

 <tr>
   <td>Doc Name</td>
   <td><input type="text" name="doc_name" id="doc_name" size="30"></td>
  </tr>
  

  
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="reset">
   </td>
   <td colspan="2">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" />
   </td>
  </tr>
  
 </table>
 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Without knowing how the user is moving from form one to form two (being automatically redirected or manually navigating), and without being able to see the form elements (they don't appear to be included in your code). I would suggest using sessions.

```
<?php
session_start()
?>

<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$age=$_POST['age'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];
$occupation=$_POST['occupation'];
$mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
$address=$_POST['address'];
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$db=@mysql_select_db("hms",$con)or die(mysql_error());
$str="insert into patients values('$id','$name','$age','$gender','$occupation','$mobile','$address')";
$res=@mysql_query($str)or die(mysql_error());

if($res>=0)
{
    echo'<br><br><b>Patient added !!<br>';
    $_SESSION['patientid'] = $id;
}

?>
<html>

<body style="background-image:url(background4.jpg)">
<br>
<a href="home.html"><b>Click here to return to the home page</b></a>
</body></html>




//end of first form addpatient//

//start of second form addprescription




<?php
session_start()
?>

<?php
$id=$_POST['id'];
$medicine=$_POST['medicine'];
$diagnosis=$_POST['diagnosis'];
$instructions=$_POST['instructions'];
$doc_name=$_POST['doc_name'];
$con=@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
$db=@mysql_select_db("hms",$con)or die(mysql_error());
$str="insert into prescription values('$id','$medicine','$diagnosis','$instructions','$doc_name')";
$res=@mysql_query($str)or die(mysql_error());
if($res>=0)
{
echo'<br><br><b>Prescription added !!<br>';
}

?>
<html>
<body style="background-image:url(background4.jpg)">
<br>
<a href="home.html"><b>Click here to return to the home page</b></a>
<form>
    <input type = "text" name = "id" value = "<?php echo $_SESSION['patientid']; ?>" />
</form>
</body></html>
```

Also, using the 'root' account for your mysql login is a big security risk. Combined with the fact that you are using the submitted values to directly insert into the database, you are wide-open to SQL-injection attacks (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

I strongly recommend using a new user account with limited permissions, and also qualifying your values before inserting them into the query string.